# Revisiting the array of strings initialization in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization

I want to initialize in plain `C` an array of strings with the following requirements:

(A) I need the strings in a header file, since some other modules are using them as plain strings, so I declared in the header file:

```
extern const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0001;
extern const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0002;
extern const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0003;
extern const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0004;
```

and in the source file:

```
const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0001 = "[VM-001] some text ";
const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0002 = "[VM-002] more text ";
const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0003 = "[VM-003] other text ";
const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0004 = "[VM-003] and even more";
```

(B) I need these strings also in an array, so I tried in the (same) source (as above):

```
static const char* error_table[4] =
{
    ERRMSG_VM_0001,
    ERRMSG_VM_0002,
    ERRMSG_VM_0003,
    ERRMSG_VM_0004
};
```

Obviously, the compiler complains `error: initializer element is not constant` ... so now I am wondering how can I achieve this in a pure `C` way, not `C++` (this is similar to [Tricky array Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100470/tricky-array-initialization) but it's not the same).

Answer (score 3):

Compilers are able to find matching string literals and optimize the binary. (it may be an option)

I'd suggest to declare defines only and create a const

```
#define ERRMSG_VM_0001 "[VM-001] some text "
...
```

and

```
static const char* error_table[4] =
{
    ERRMSG_VM_0001,
    ERRMSG_VM_0002,
    ERRMSG_VM_0003,
    ERRMSG_VM_0004
};
```

would be now OK.
and the resulting binary code will be the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
static const char* error_table[4] =
{
    "[VM-001] some text ",
    "[VM-002] some text ",
    "[VM-003] some text ",
    "[VM-004] some text ",
};
```

then

```
ERRMSG_VM_0001 = error_table[0];
```

Comment: strangely, now it complains: `const char* ERRMSG_VM_0001 = error_table[0];` as `initializer element is not constant` ... and even stripping all the consts is not working

Answer (score 0):

The `ERRMSG_VM_0001` is a variable. But in C++ it will be a constant expression. That is why C++ allows the same but C wont allow it.
You can't do this in C.

```
const int a = 10;
const int arr[] = { a };
```

You can do like this...

```
//Is in header.h
extern const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0001;
extern const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0002;
extern const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0003;
extern const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0004;

//This is in main.c
#include "header.h" 
static const char* error_table[4] =
{
    "[VM-001] some text ",
    "[VM-002] some text ",
    "[VM-003] some text ",
    "[VM-004] some text ",
};

int main(void)
{
    const char* const ERRMSG_VM_0001 = error_table[0]; // Works fine
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But in this case the other modules using `ERRMSG_VM_0001` will not see its definition ...

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to change type of the array elements from char* to char**, array can be inplace initialized:

```
static const char* const* const error_table[4] =
{
    &ERRMSG_VM_0001,
    &ERRMSG_VM_0002,
    &ERRMSG_VM_0003,
    &ERRMSG_VM_0004
};
```